# How to copy files that having line number > 100 to other folder

Tags: shell, file, unix, copy

I want to copy files that having 100 lines or more to another folder:

```
$ cd "/home/john/folder a"  
$ wc -l *
10 file1.txt
50 file2.txt
100 file3.txt
150 file4.txt
```

I want to copy file `file3.txt` and `file4.txt` (files that having 100 lines or more) to folder `/home/john/folder b`.

Can someone help me please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare -i numfile
for f in *; do
  numfile=$([ -f "$f" ] && cat "$f" | wc -l )
  [ $numfile -ge 100 ] && cp "$f" otherdir
done
```

For each files in current directory, `numfile` is assigned the number of lines of the file.

If `numfile` is greater or equal to 100, file is copied to `otherdir`.

**Edit :**

As William Pursell mentionned, a more robust approach would be to test if the item is a file **before** executing comparison and copy commands:

```
for f in *; do 
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    [ "$(wc -l < $f)" -ge 100 ] && cp "$f" otherdir;
  fi
done
```

Comment: I suppose your answer is definitely more to the point than mine :)

Comment: Relying on the declaration of numfile as an integer smells bad.  For example,  if the test is reversed to copy files with less than 100 lines, this will attempt to copy directories.  Probably safer to just append `&&` at the end of the line making the numfile assignment, or write `for f in *; do test -f "$f" && test "$(wc -l < $f)" -ge 100 && cp "$f" /path; done`

Comment: what does [ -f "$f" ] mean ?

Comment: @Jiangty `[ -f "$f" ]` is a test to check if the item assigned to the `"$f"` variable is a regular file: `-f`. See more: [File test operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more:

```
# Assuming that we are in source folder ...
cp $(wc -l *|grep -Eo '[0-9]{3,} (.*)'|head -n -1|cut -d ' ' -f 2) /dev/null "/home/john/folder b"
```

The `head` removes the *total* line printed by `wc`, and the `/dev/null` takes care of the case that you don't have any files matching the criterium.

Of course this solution - as the other ones presented here - will get you into problems, if your source directory contains that many files, that the maximum command line length will be exceeded.

Comment: I like the idea, but using a regex match for the numerical comparison seems fragile.  Probably easier to do `wc -l * | awk '$1 > 100{print $2}' ...`   There are still issues with directories.

Comment: In my solution, directories are implicitly ignored. I don't see a problem with the regex match for the numbers either, except with one (slightliy pathological case), where my approach would fail: Imagine a file named `200 xx` (i.e. the name starts with a three digit number and has a space embedded); with my solution, the file would be copied even if it has less than 100 lines. Of course who would create files with embedded spaces in the name....  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (POSIX sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
SOURCE_FOLDER="/home/john/folder a"
COPY_TO="/home/john/folder b"

for dir in "$SOURCE_FOLDER" "$COPY_TO"; do
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
        echo "Directory ${dir} does not exist." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

if [ "x`ls -A "$SOURCE_FOLDER"`" = "x" ]; then
    echo "Directory '${SOURCE_FOLDER}' is empty." >&2
    exit 1
fi

for file in "$SOURCE_FOLDER"/*; do
    LINES=`wc -l < "$file"`
    echo "File ${file} has ${LINES} lines..."

    if [ "$LINES" -ge 100 ]; then
        echo "Copying ${file}..."
        cp -a "$file" "${COPY_TO}/"
    fi
done
```

Here's a Bash version for systems with Bash (you said Unix, not Linux, so you probably want the top version):

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE_FOLDER="/home/john/folder a"
COPY_TO="/home/john/folder b"

for dir in "$SOURCE_FOLDER" "$COPY_TO"; do
    if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]]; then
        echo "Directory ${dir} does not exist." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

if [[ -z "$(ls -A "$SOURCE_FOLDER")" ]]; then
    echo "Directory '${SOURCE_FOLDER}' is empty." >&2
    exit 1
fi

for file in "$SOURCE_FOLDER"/*; do
    LINES="$(wc -l < "$file"')"
    echo "File ${file} has ${LINES} lines..."

    if [[ "$LINES" -ge 100 ]]; then
        echo "Copying ${file}..."
        cp -a "$file" "${COPY_TO}/"
    fi
done
```

I tested it like this:

```
$  mkdir "folder a"
$  mkdir "folder b"
$  chmod +x script.sh
$  cd folder\ a/
$  seq 1 1000 > file1.txt
$  seq 1 1000 > file2.txt
$  seq 1 100 > file4.txt
$  seq 1 100 > file3.txt
$  seq 1 99 > file4.txt
$  seq 1 1 > file5.txt
$  seq 1 20 > file6.txt
$  cd ..
$ ./script.sh
File /.../dev/scratch/stack/folder a/file1.txt has 1000 lines...
Copying /.../dev/scratch/stack/folder a/file1.txt...
File /.../dev/scratch/stack/folder a/file2.txt has 1000 lines...
Copying /.../dev/scratch/stack/folder a/file2.txt...
File /.../dev/scratch/stack/folder a/file3.txt has 100 lines...
Copying /.../dev/scratch/stack/folder a/file3.txt...
File /.../dev/scratch/stack/folder a/file4.txt has 99 lines...
File /.../dev/scratch/stack/folder a/file5.txt has 1 lines...
File /.../dev/scratch/stack/folder a/file6.txt has 20 lines...
```

I encourage you to step through this line by line, figuring out how each part of the script works, to help you with similar tasks in the future.

I'll explain a few things here:

- `wc -l < "$file"` gives us only the line count of the file, without the filename.
- `[ "$LINES" -ge 100 ]` is true if there are at least 100 lines in the file.
- `echo "..." >&2` outputs a line to standard error rather than standard output.
- `cp -a` copys a file while retaining all of it's attributes, such as owner, permissions, and  modification time.
- Make sure to quote all variables unless you have a good reason not to, to prevent issues with whitespace.

Comment: You don't need a pipe to get the line count. `wc -l <"$file"` would do too.